# Force Google Chrome to display blank page on reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, page-refresh

I see if we reload page in IE/Edge or Chrome/Firefox there is a big difference.
IE/Edge cleans the page and shows white page but Chrome/Firefox  does  not.

Is it possible somehow using JavaScript to say  Chrome/Firefox like hey, please show me the blank page instead of the current page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it.

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        $("html,body").hide();        
    };
```